# How to refresh token with Flutter Http Retry Client?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am storing API request result with Token and refresh token sharedpreferences. Refresh time is 1 hour.

When the token expires, the token is renewed with RetryClient, but it is not reflected in the application. This process only happens when you refresh the page. Where am I doing wrong? What I want to do is when you give the 401 status code, it will automatically renew the token on the back and make a request again.

```
Future<HttpResult> post(url,
  {Map<String, String>? headers, String? body}) async {
final client = RetryClient(Client(), retries: 1, when: (response) {
  return response.statusCode == 401 ? true : false;
}, onRetry: (req, res, retryCount) async {
  await refreshToken(); //
});
try {
  final response = await client.post(url, headers: headers, body: body);
  return HttpResult(data: response.body, status: _setStatus(response));
} catch(e) {
}
```

}

```
Future addFood(Food food) async {
try {
  final token = SharedManager.instance.getStringValue(SharedKeys.TOKEN);

  Uri endpoint =
      Uri.https(AppConstant.apiServiceUrl, 'foods.json', {"auth": token});

  final jsonModel = jsonEncode(food.toJson());
  final request = await httpClient.post(endpoint, body: jsonModel);

  if (request.status == Status.success) {;
    return "Success";
  }

  return "Don't.";
} catch (e) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I returned that method when the Status Code was 401, I solved the problem.

```
Future addFood(Food food) async {
    try {
      final token = SharedManager.instance.getStringValue(SharedKeys.TOKEN);
    
      Uri endpoint =
          Uri.https(AppConstant.apiServiceUrl, 'foods.json', {"auth": token});
    
      final jsonModel = jsonEncode(food.toJson());
      final request = await httpClient.post(endpoint, body: jsonModel);
    
      if (request.status == Status.success) { //enum -> success (200)
        return "Success";
      }if (result.status == Status.unauthorized) { //enum -> unauthrozied (401)
            return addFood(food);
      }
    
      return "Don't.";
    } catch (e) {}
```